# How to use ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a website that allows users to follow certain stocks and read articles based on what they follow. I am having trouble creating a form for them to follow stocks as a user's `Profile` and `Stocks` have a many to many relationship, I believe I am supposed to use `ModelMultipleChoiceField` but cannot get it to work.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save



class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()

class Article(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = 0 )
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from .models import Stock
    from django.forms import ModelMultipleChoiceField


    class ProfileRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name' ,'last_name')

    class StockFollowForm():
        stocks = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Stock.objects.all())
```

views.py

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StockFollowForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.user.profile.followed_stocks = form.cleaned_data.get('stocks_selected')
            request.user.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = StockFollowForm()
        return render(request, 'core/test.html',{'form': form})
```

template:

```
{%  block body %}
    <div class = "container">
        <h2 class = "text-center">Register</h2>

        <form method = 'post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <div class = "text-center">
                <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type = 'submit'>Login</button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

When I run this code no form is displayed. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem? Was my answer below useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

I think your form class has to inherit from djangos form, like the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-form-class) show.

Change

```
class StockFollowForm():
```

to

```
from django import forms
class StockFollowForm(forms.Form):
```